# `tikz-cd` diagram is not rendered when there are labels on arrows

Tags: diagrams, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I am using `tikz-cd` for the first time, trying to create a rather simple commutative diagram. This is the first part of the diagram I am trying to get to render:

```
\begin{tikzcd}
    R \arrow[r, "T_R"] & T_R\left(R\right) \arrow[r, "G", dashed] & T_S\left(S\right) & S \arrow[l, "T_S"']
\end{tikzcd}
```

Unfortunately, as soon as I add the labels to the arrows (the things in quotes), the diagram is not rendered. I just get a bunch of errors, starting with

```
pdflatex.exe> ! Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }.
pdflatex.exe> <inserted text> 
pdflatex.exe>                 \par 
pdflatex.exe> l.527             \end{tikzcd}
pdflatex.exe>                      
pdflatex.exe> Runaway argument?
pdflatex.exe> ! Paragraph ended before \language@active@arg" was complete.
pdflatex.exe> <to be read again> 
pdflatex.exe>                    \par 
pdflatex.exe> l.527             \end{tikzcd}
```

and then repeating

```
pdflatex.exe> ! Missing \endcsname inserted.
pdflatex.exe> <to be read again> 
pdflatex.exe>                    \@@par 
pdflatex.exe> l.527             \end{tikzcd}
```

a bunch of times. It works fine without arrow labels, but I definitely need those. What am I doing wrong here?

In case you might need it, these are the packages I currently use:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, titlepage, twoside]{article} %TODO: Remove draft

% LOADING PACKAGES
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Encoding
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %language
\usepackage{csquotes} %Needed by babael/biblate}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[backend=biber, safeinputenc, backref=true, hyperref=auto, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}% bibliography
\usepackage{enumitem} %Easier enumeration item labelling
%\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage{mathtools} %Better colon-equal alignment
\usepackage{amsmath} %Math tools
\usepackage{amsthm, thmtools} %Theorem tools
\usepackage{chngcntr} %Automatically reset equation numbering in new sections
\usepackage{amssymb} %special symbols
\usepackage{interval} %Nicer and simpler intervals
\usepackage{braket} %nice left & right <.,.> brackets and sets
\usepackage[pdftex, colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref} %Linking
\usepackage{graphicx} %Images
%\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{geometry} %Lines
%\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{multicol} %Title page multicolumn
\usepackage{titling} %Titling
\usepackage{xcolor} %Coloring (may be removed once colored text is removed) TODO
\usepackage{tikz-cd} %Kommutative Diagramme
```

Comment: Try adding `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` after `\usepackage{tikz-cd}` and check if the problems disappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I confirm the problem without `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`, and it is solved by adding `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`, which makes the `quotes` library coexist with `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` (in this case). Some of the packages you are loading you do not need to load explicitly because they get loaded anyway.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, titlepage, twoside]{article} %TODO: Remove draft

% LOADING PACKAGES
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Encoding
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %language
\usepackage{csquotes} %Needed by babael/biblate}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[backend=biber, safeinputenc, backref=true, hyperref=auto, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}% bibliography
\usepackage{enumitem} %Easier enumeration item labelling
%\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage{mathtools} %Better colon-equal alignment
\usepackage{amsmath} %Math tools
\usepackage{amsthm, thmtools} %Theorem tools
\usepackage{chngcntr} %Automatically reset equation numbering in new sections
\usepackage{amssymb} %special symbols
\usepackage{interval} %Nicer and simpler intervals
\usepackage{braket} %nice left & right <.,.> brackets and sets
\usepackage[pdftex, colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref} %Linking
% \usepackage{graphicx} %Images gets loaded by tikz, which gets loaded by tikz-cd
%\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{geometry} %Lines
%\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{multicol} %Title page multicolumn
\usepackage{titling} %Titling
% \usepackage{xcolor} %Coloring (may be removed once colored text is removed) TODO
% ^^^ also gets loaded by tikz
\usepackage{tikz-cd} %Kommutative Diagramme
\usetikzlibrary{babel}% added
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
    R \arrow[r, "T_R"] & T_R\left(R\right) \arrow[r, "G", dashed] & T_S\left(S\right) & S \arrow[l, "T_S"']
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this solved the issue. I already suspected this to be the cause but didn't find any hints about that in the `tikz-cd`documentation.